# Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 when mocha unit testing

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm getting this error when unit testing code,

> 2 passing (14ms)   1 failing
>
> 1) Uncaught error outside test suite:
>        Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
>         at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1255:14)
>         at listenInCluster (net.js:1303:12)
>         at Server.listen (net.js:1391:7)
>         at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>         at Object.listen (main.js:39:5)
>         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
>         at Module._compile (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
>         at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
>         at Object.newLoader [as .js] (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
>         at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
>         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
>         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>         at Object. (test/main.test.js:4:1)
>         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
>         at Module._compile (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
>         at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
>         at Object.newLoader [as .js] (node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
>         at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
>         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
>         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>         at Array.forEach ()
>         at StatWatcher.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:50:8)

I'm using [mocha](https://mochajs.org), and i have `--watch` on my package.json. I'm using an es6 approach to express.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "elies6express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --watch --require @babel/register",
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bookshelf": "^0.14.2",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "knex": "^0.16.5",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^7.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "reify": "^0.19.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import userRoute from './routes/users';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
// For React Stuff if need be
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.use('/users', userRoute);

app.use(() => (req, res, next)  =>{
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 

//build mode
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/public/index.html'));
// })

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
);

export default app;
```

**main.test.js**

```
import chai from "chai"
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import request from 'request';
import server from '../main';
const expect = chai.expect;
const should = chai.should();


chai.use(chaiHttp);

// should get / 

describe('should GET /',  () => {
    it('should get 200 status', (done) =>{
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/')
        .end( (err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });

})
// should check for Hello World!
describe('Should check for Hello World! text', () => {
    it('should check for hello world text', (done) =>{
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/')
        .end( (err, res) => {
            expect(res.body).to.be.an('object') // works
            expect(res.text).to.equal('Hello World!')  // use res.text to check for res.send() text
            done();
        })
    })

})
```

Answer (score 8):

In `main.js`, place your `app.listen` call inside a test for `!module.parent`, like this:

```
if(!module.parent){
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
  );
}
```

Source: http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/10/eaddrinuse-when-watching-tests-with-mocha-and-supertest.html

Answer (score 5):

The earlier linked

```
if (!module.parent) {
```

is deprecated as of v14.6.0, v12.19.0. ([documentation link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent))

One solution is to use the following:

```
if (require.main === module) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`"testwatch": "nodemon --exec \"mocha --recursive\""`

will `100%` server your purpose until test library posts something more relevant

Answer (score 0):

This looks very hacky, but what worked for me was making sure that, for every suite of tests, I would be using a different port.

Answer (score -1):

It means that something is running on port 3000 already. You need to stop that and then start your application. Or just change the port of your application to something else.

To free up port 3000  use :

`fuser -k 3000/tcp`

or

```
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
```

To change the port of your application :

```
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`),
);
```

Comment: thanks but this does not solve the issue, i tried that, the problem still persists. Keep in mind im using mochas --watch feature. I want to be able to make edits on code while npm test is running. I don't want to keep `npm test` everytime i make a code change.